# Run script automatically after creating a new Xcode project

Tags: xcode, git, templates, project, git-submodules

I've created a custom project template the needs to add a few submodules upon creation of the new project. I have the `git submodule add ...` command added to a `.sh` file. So is it possible to automatically run the script after creating the project without having to add it to the Build Phases? Maybe through the `TemplateInfo.plist`? If you know any alternatives or better routes to take, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Considering a submodule is just a reference to a fixed SHA1, you could simply add them directly to your template project.

That way, any new project would already benefit from said submodules.